# r.terraflow fails on Mac (rusage/gettimeofday: Bad address)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to get flow lines, flow accumulation and stream segments form a raster DEM. The DEM is about 2000x3000 cells.

I loaded this into GRASS (v7.3, running on Mac OS El Capitan) using a .prj projection definition because it is in a non-EPSG CRS. I set the region to fit the raster and match the cell alignment.

When I run r.terraflow I get a warning:

```
WARNING: raster Rush_Creek_DEM is of type DCELL_TYPE --precision may be lost.
```

The command ends with:

```
rusage/gettimeofday: Bad address
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

The entire output using the --verbose flag, shown below:

```
r.terraflow --verbose elevation=Rush_Creek_DEM@PERMANENT filled=Rush_Creek_DEM_fill direction=Rush_Creek_DEM_flowdir swatershed=Rush_Creek_DEM_watershed accumulation=Rush_Creek_DEM_flowaccum tci=Rush_Creek_DEM_tci
Memory manager registering memory in MM_WARN_ON_MEMORY_EXCEEDED mode.
cell Rush_Creek_DEM header compatible with region header
Elevation stored as FLOAT (4B)
WARNING: raster Rush_Creek_DEM is of type DCELL_TYPE --precision may be lost.
Region size is 2129 x 3212
STREAM temporary files in /Users/brendan/grassdata/Rush_Cree
k/PERMANENT/.tmp/MBP.local/13929.0  (THESE INTERMEDIATE
STREAMS WILL NOT BE DELETED IN CASE OF ABNORMAL TERMINATION
OF THE PROGRAM. TO SAVE SPACE PLEASE DELETE THESE FILES
MANUALLY!)
Reading data from <Rush_Creek_DEM> to stream </Users/brendan/grassdata/Rush_Creek/PERMANENT/.tmp/MBP.local/13929.0/STREAM_baaaaX>
total elements=6838348, nodata elements=145083
largest temporary files:
FILL: 365.21M (382947488) [6838348 elements, 56B each]
FLOW: 510.66M (535461200) [6693265 elements, 80B each]
Will need at least 1021.31M (1070922400) space available in /Users/brendan/grassdata/Rush_Creek/PERMANENT/.tmp/MBP.local/13929.0
EMPQUEUEADAPTIVE: starting in-memory pqueue
EMPQUEUEADAPTIVE: available memory: 297.99MB
EMPQUEUEADAPTIVE: desired memory: 297.99MB
sz_stream: 263232 buf_arity: 200 mm_overhead: 8437120 mm_avail: 312465395.
EMPQUEUEADAPTIVE: memory overhead set to 8.04626MB
EMPQUEUEADAPTIVE: pqsize set to 38003534
rusage/gettimeofday: Bad address
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the GRASS GIS version which you are using here

Comment: Sidenote: Apparently this issue was already discussed: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2016-January/073522.html but without a solution

Comment: Thanks for looking into it Markus. I did see that thread but wasn't able to learn much from it. I am using GRASS 7.3 and have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Could you make the GRASS GIS location available for a test? I have no Mac but I could try to check on Linux. The best is that you open a new ticket here: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ (the error comes from include/iostream/rtimer.h but better to discuss this in a ticket!). Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about making the GRASS location available, but I suppose I would need some sort of server for that…? I'd be open to making it available if theres an easy way but I don't have anything like that set up yet. In any case, I'll open up a ticket on OSGEO.

Comment: If only one raster map is involved, then you can export it with r.pack along with the EPSG code or .prj file to recreate the location elsewhere. But open the ticket anyway, then we can discuss there further on.

Comment: What about the solution to the thread linked above? I wrote that question, and solved it by using `r.watershed` instead of `r.terraflow`?

Comment: I don't have an OSGeo account, so I am currently waiting to be approved for a user ID. Once I have an ID I will open a ticket for this issue. @mankoff I was ultimately able to use r.watershed on this raster, but I would still be interested in figuring out what is going wrong here.

Comment: if you don't get the OSGeo account soon (it is actually to be manually approved due to heavy spam problems with human "bots"), pls drop me an email and I'll do that

Comment: Hi Markus, not sure how to email you but I am still waiting on approval to OSGeo so if you feel inclined / don't mind submitting a ticket it would be much appreciated.